# How do I create a randomly generated matrix with randomly generated dimension and then transpose it?

Tags: numpy, matrix, random, transpose

This is what I have so far:

```
import random
import numpy as np
r1 = random.randint(0, 100)
r2 = random.randint(0, 100)
r3 = random.randint(0, 100)
if r2 < r1:
    print("invalid")
elif r2 < r3:
    print("invalid")
a = np.arange(r2).reshape((r1, r3))
print(a)
print(a.transpose())
```

basically, I created 3 variables with random numbers in a arange from 1 to 100, and I think I misued the if/else statement and also messed up the np.arange().reshape() part of the program.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The issue here is that most times you can't reshape into arbitrary 2D shape `(r1, r3)` your input array `np.arange(r2)`. You will notice this, if you run your code, you'll get `cannot reshape array of size ... into shape (..., ...)`.

Comment: What's the error or wrong result?  Why the transpose?

Comment: Basically it says that i cant reshape the array of a certain size into the shape. Even if the array is larger than the shape. now I did:

`import random
import numpy as np
r1 = random.randint(0, 100)
r2 = random.randint(0, 100)
a = np.arange(101).reshape((r1, r2))
print(a)
print(a.transpose())`

but it still doesnt work.

Comment: `reshape` cannot change the total number of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You trying to reshape an array of shape `r2` into a array of shape `r1, r3` which in most case is not possible. It's like trying to arange `r2` elements into a `r1 x r3` grid. Your problem is over constrained. For this to work `r2` needs to be equal to `r1*r3`.

I'm not sure what your ultimate goal is but you could just randomly get `r1` and `r3` and then set `r2` as `r1*r3`. This will essentially reshape an `r1*r3` arangement into shape `(r1, r3)`.

```
r1 = random.randint(0, 100)
r3 = random.randint(0, 100)
a = np.arange(r1*r3).reshape(r1, r3)

print(a)
print(a.transpose())
```

Comment: Thank you fro your help!